# Issue installing pg-native dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, npm, pg

I'm currently struggling with installing the pg-native dependency to my project folder.  When I try to run my index.js, it says it cannot "resolve the dependency pg-native" though I don't believe I call it.  However, assuming that I do, I tried to install the dependency and get this error screen when I try to:

```
C:\Users\jmurr\Documents\MSDPP-Map>npm i pg-native

> libpq@1.8.9 install C:\Users\jmurr\Documents\MSDPP-Map\node_modules\libpq
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\jmurr\Documents\MSDPP-Map\node_modules\libpq>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\jmurr\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\jmurr\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
'pg_config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\jmurr\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jmurr\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v8.11.4\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jmurr\Documents\MSDPP-Map\node_modules\libpq
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN msdpp_map@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN msdpp_map@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! libpq@1.8.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libpq@1.8.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jmurr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-14T02_44_05_069Z-debug.log
```

I tried my best to set everything up properly before installing as noted under the Windows section here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-native.  However, it still does not work.  I might've done one of the things incorrectly and am hoping that somebody here can help with the frustrations I've been having the past couple of days trying to figure this out.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try npm i -g pg-native. I've been learning NPM lately and struggle with things not being found due to how the PATHS are setup. It won't hurt anything running it with -g I'm thinking that if your global is in the path it should pick it up.

Comment: Unfortunately getting the same issues @Elijah :(